# How to change the DISPLAY that an X application is running on (in Linux)?

Tags: linux, x11, display

I know that I can specify what display an X client runs on with a command like

```
 gedit --display :0
```

in Linux.
I want to move an application to a different display after it has started.
How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "runtime"? Do you mean when you're starting the application from a UI or toolbar?

Comment: I mean when the application is running. not when the application starts

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/58018/in-linux-can-i-send-a-running-window-to-a-new-display

Answer (score 2):

[Xpra](http://xpra.org/) is an application that describes itself as "screen for X".

Note that it requires that you use `xpra` to start the application in the first place. If you start an application in the normal way, it's tied to the specific display you attached it to, and it's too late to move it (just like `screen` can't adopt a command that was started outside it).